# how to set application property variable with system eviroment

Tags: spring-boot, variables, system, application.properties

I need to set applcation properties variable with system variable Ex.

my system variable enviroment on widows is USER_NAME = admin

I want that set spring.datasource.username with USER_NAME

I tryed to do this mode:

in application.properties file
  spring.datasource.username={USER_NAME}

but dind't set.

anybody knows how to do?

Comment: Use dollar sign like dollarsign{USER_NAME}.

Comment: don't work I put this: pring.datasource.username=${DB_OR4ADM_USER} exception null point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application properties the values should be with lower case and separated by point:

```
spring.datasource.username=${user.name}
```

Your environment variable should be as you've mentioned:

```
USER_NAME=admin
```